# add filters with foselasticabundle request

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I have a sf2 service to make a search request on an elasticasearch server with foselasticabundle. Initialy i made a request with a filter:

```
public function findAll()
{
    $query = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();
    $response = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered($query, self::setFilter());
    return $response;
}

public function setFilter()
{
    $filter = new \Elastica\Filter\Bool();
    $filter->addMust(new \Elastica\Filter\Term(array('active' => true)));
    return $filter;
}
```

In my controller i get the count of this request :

```
    $search = $this->get("mb.search");
    $query = $search->findAll();
    $nbOnline = $this->get("fos_elastica.index.xxxx.yy")->count($query);
```

This code work fine. I would like to add a filter based on a array :

```
$languages = array(1,3,5)
```

I didn't find the good way too add this new filter in my query. I hope you can help me on this case. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use "[Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-terms-filter.html)" filter for this task, [here is](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/master/lib/Elastica/Filter/Terms.php) the PHP implementation.

You code should be looked like this:

```
new \Elastica\Filter\Terms(array('MY_FIELD' => array(1,3,5)))
```

Comment: thanks, i add this on my method :  $filter->addMust(new \Elastica\Filter\Terms(array('language' => $this->languages))); but now i have an error Warning: Illegal offset type 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Comment: @Olivier I don't your index structure, I don't know why are you receiving this error.. Try to create a request to your index with  Sense plugin (Google chrome), then convert it to PHP.

Comment: thanks for your help, i found the solution, the good syntax is new \Elastica\Filter\Terms('MY_FIELD', $array)

Comment: @Olivier Ah yes, I see it [here](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/master/lib/Elastica/Filter/Terms.php#L42), Looks like I need to refresh my skills with ES:) . I'm glad you found the solution.